# Calling django view from AJAX request (parsing celery task_id)

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, celery, django-urls

I'm trying to output data from a celery task into a separate window. I'm a novice to `JavaScript` and `AJAX`, and this is where my current issue lies. After a view is executed, the celery task is initiated and the next html page (`success.html`) is rendered:

**success.html**

```
{% block content %}
  <body>
    {% if task_id %}
      <h1>task_id has been called: {{ task_id }}</h1>

    <script src="{% static 'MyAPP/bootstrap/js/task_output_retrieval.js' %}"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'> task_state("{{ task_id }}"); </script>

    <script src="{% static 'MyAPP/bootstrap/js/update-hello-user.js' %}"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'> second(); </script>

      <h1> END </h1>

    {% endif %}
  </body>
{% endblock content %}
```

I know the `JavaScript` is called, because a window is at least opened. Here is the `.js`:

**task_output_retrieval.js**

```
function task_state (task_id) {
    var taskID = task_id; 
    var newWin = window.open('', 'new window', 'width=200, height=100');

    $.ajax({
            url: '{% url validate_task_state %}', 
            data: {'taskID':taskID},
            method: 'POST',
            dataType : "json",
            success: function(data){
                $(newWin.document.body).html(data);
                newWin.document.write(data);
                newWin.document.close();
                newWin.focus();
                newWin.print();
                newWin.close();
            },
            error: function (){ alert('An error occured'); }
    });
}

task_state(task_id);
```

And the **url.py**:

```
url(r'^ajax/task_state/$', task_state, name='validate_task_state'), # for ajax
```

And the view:

**admin_scripts.py**

```
def task_state(request):
    print ("You reached the task_state function")
    data = 'Fail' 
    task_id = request.GET.get('task_id') 
    #task_id = request.session['task_id']
    try:
        async_result = AsyncResult(task_id)
    except KeyError:
        ret = {'error':'No optimisation (or you may have disabled cookies).'}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ret))

    print ("request.is_ajax(): {0}".format(request.is_ajax()))
    if request.is_ajax():
        if 'task_id' in request.POST.keys() and request.POST['task_id']:
            task_id = request.POST['task_id']
            async_result.get() 
            data = {
            'state': async_result.state,
            'result': async_result.result,
            }
            #data = async_result.result or async_result.state
            print ("data: {0}".format(data))
        else:
            data = 'No task_id in the request'
    else:
        raise SuspiciousOperation("This is not an ajax request.")

    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

There are still many open issues in the `task_state` I don't fully understand and through trial and error I'll get there, but right now, the `task_state` is not being called. The problem I suspect is with the AJAX call (the "url") but I can't figure out why. Where am I going wrong?

**Update:** After checking the "JS Test Stuff" checkbox, the `success.html` is rendered, error free. The AJAX JavaScript (`task_output_retrieval.js`) is called from within `success.html`, and this is verified because from the `success.html` I'm calling 2 JavaScript files (the other being `update-hello-user.js`). The window from `task_output_retrieval.js` is opened and popup from `update-hello-user.js` is also shown. It's within the task_output_retrieval.js where I'm calling the view:

```
    $.ajax({
                url: query_url,
)
```

but this is not rendered.

Here is the output from console:

```
[17/Aug/2018 04:59:12] INFO [django.server:124] "GET /MyApp/opt/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6631
async_result f2224e67-3e47-4980-9dc8-58622928e090
TASK_ID f2224e67-3e47-4980-9dc8-58622928e090
[17/Aug/2018 04:59:14] INFO [django.server:124] "POST /MyApp/opt/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6412
[17/Aug/2018 04:59:14] INFO [django.server:124] "GET /MyAppsite-static/MyApp/bootstrap/js/update-hello-user.js HTTP/1.1" 200 52
[17/Aug/2018 04:59:14] INFO [django.server:124] "GET /MyAppsite-static/MyApp/bootstrap/js/task_output_retrieval.js HTTP/1.1" 200 640
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue that jumps at me looking at your code is your use of `{% url validate_task_state %}` inside a JavaScript file. If you follow the most common recommended method to setup Django and serve its static content, your JavaScript files won't be processed by the template engine, and **that template tag won't be processed**. Also, it needs quotes around its argument so `{% 'url validate_task_state' %}`

You should change your `success.html` template to pass the requried URL to your `task_state` function, like this:

```
<script src="{% static 'MyAPP/bootstrap/js/task_output_retrieval.js' %}"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'> task_state("{% url 'validate_task_state' %}", "{{ task_id }}"); </script>
```

And modify your function to take the new argument:

```
function task_state (query_url, task_id) {
    var taskID = task_id; 
    var newWin = window.open('', 'new window', 'width=200, height=100');

    $.ajax({
            url: query_url, 
            data: {'taskID':taskID},
            method: 'POST',
            dataType : "json",
            success: function(data){
                $(newWin.document.body).html(data);
                newWin.document.write(data);
                newWin.document.close();
                newWin.focus();
                newWin.print();
                newWin.close();
            },
            error: function (){ alert('An error occured'); }
    });
}
```

---

You've said in a comment that Django is not seeing the request. A common issue is CSRF protection: a custom POST request needs to pass the CSRF token, or it will be rejected. The details of how to do it depend in part on your specific configuration but generally, I do:

```
// Grab the CSRF token from the cookie.
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "... my url ...",
  headers: {
    // Pass the token with the query.
    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
  },
  // other ajax options...
});
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Changing my code has thrown the error: `Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` It has something to do with the `url: query_url`, which I also changed to `url: 'query_url',`but didn't seem to resolve the error message. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: The quotes are needed for the argument to `{% url ... %}`. So `{% 'url validate_task_state' %}`, with quotes around the argument. I've edited my answer just now to fix that. I wrote the answer by rearranging your code and did not notice the missing quotes, at first. You definitely should **not** change `url: query_url` to `url: 'query_url'`. `url: query_url` is correct. It sets the `url` option to the value of the `query_url` parameter of the function, which is in turned set to the value of `{% url '...' %}` in your Django template.

Comment: the change you recommended helped remove the error message, and at least the error box and window opens, however the `view` function `task_state` is not called as the print statement would at least be executed it was. I suspect the url in the `url.py`, but changing this has so far not worked.

Comment: I'm also there, and would like to award this answer as the correct answer, just the small step (why my view from the AJAX call is not being called) is missing. Is this an issue with there the .js and view.py files are located compared to one another, my mapping in url.py, or something else? I don't see an error message any more, but this little bit of code doesn't work like I'd like it to.

Comment: There's a whole slew of possible problems that can prevent your request from being answered. One *relatively common* culprit is CSRF protection so I've added that to my answer. If that's not your issue then there are a lot of other problems that can occur. You need to perform some debugging. Open the developer tools in your browser and see what response your query gets. What's the status code 404? 400? 502? Something else? In development mode, Django also reports information on the console. Does it report something that corresponds to your failed query?

Comment: I just edited my original post, please see everything below "Update". Also when I open "Console" when inspecting my code (in Chrome) I get: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at task_state (task_output_retrieval.js:5)
    at (index):127` This (127) corresponds to `    <script type='text/javascript'> task_state("/MyApp/dff03f07-b573-45f6-8058-e25612655655/ajax/task_state/", "dff03f07-b573-45f6-8058-e25612655655"); </script>`

Comment: your other comments about CSRF I'll have to check still.

Comment: @Louise: In my `url.py I have: `        url(r'^(?P<task_id>[\w-]+)/ajax/task_state/$', task_state, name='validate_task_state'), # for ajax`and so I'm wondering if this is the culprit.